# What's the actual grammar and semantics of "Where We Go One We Go All"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Recently the bizarre conspiracy theorists who label themselves as "QAnon" have made an appearance in the news. They are cited with the slogan *Where We Go One We Go All* (mostly expressed through the acronym *WWG1WGA*).

I'm not an English native speaker and confused about the grammar and semantics of this slogan. Does it mean: "Where one of us goes, we all go?" And if not, what does it actually mean? And is there an explanation for the odd grammar? Are there other (older) examples for such a grammatical usage? Is it (pseudo) Old English?

I guess the *We Go One* part (apparently standing for "one goes") is particularly irritating to me because the plural **we** appears to be the grammatical subject while the singular **one** appears to be the subject in terms of semantics.

Comment: I'd call it highly stylised "poetic inversion" - of an original something like *We all go where one [of us] goes.* I don't think it's particularly "pseudo Old English" - it's just "pithy sloganising" that perhaps acquires "pseudo gravitas" from its ***poetic*** associations. (It alludes to / reflects The Three Musketeers ***Un pour tous, tous pour un*** - "All for one and one for all".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Middle English use of *one* meaning "alone, only" which functions as an adverb and can be used as in "where we go one". This sense is marked as "obsolete" in the OED.

The OED (**one**, sense A.II.5.d) gives some examples including:

> Mordred..Callyd hys folke And sayd to hem One (*Morte Arthur*, c. 1400, "said to them only")

> Of noþyng certis doþ þay drede bot of liflode one. (*Sir Ferumbras*, c. 1380, "fearful of nothing but their livelihoods alone")

> Naut ane under his hond, ac under his fet (*MS Lamb*, c. 1225; "not only ... but ...")

*All* still functions as an adverb according to the OED.

It's clear they mean "Where we go alone/singly, we go together". It's less clear if they got this from Middle English; by analogy with "go all"/"go together"; by chance, e.g. by dropping a word such as "as" for reasons of how it sounds; or by a fondness for the Three Musketeers.

Source: "one, adj., n., and pron." OED Online, Oxford University Press, September 2022, [www.oed.com/view/Entry/131358](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131358). Accessed 27 September 2022.

Answer (score -1):

I think that they are applying their rejection of rules in general to a flaunting of grammatical norms.  I'm guessing that it's probably the result of an instinctive attempt to appear rebellious rather than a thought-out choice.

Comment: I think you meant to say "flouting" - "flaunting" doesn't make sense in context.